# Conflicts with different versions

Tags: breeze, breeze-sharp

I installed the Breeze Sharp client, but get the following warning.

> Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent
>   assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it
>   and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following
>   binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application
>   configuration file:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.13.0" newVersion="4.2.13.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: I updated the question with additional information. I'm seeing this issue after Breeze Sharp Client is installed. None of my other projects references Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: Does the app run without adding the binding redirect?  We've had several issues with building nuget packages for Microsoft Portable Class Libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using the latest Breeze.Sharp Nuget ( 0.5.9.0 or greater)  and let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: I installed the latest version of 0.6.0.2 from nugget. I don't see the error anymore.